# Difficulty with getting local GeoPosition correctly

Tags: geography, geographics

I am using the wolfram cloud on a Chromebook and when I type the function `Here` it returns a faulty `GeoPosition[{38.1103,-78.9073}]`.

In fact, I have four Chromebooks here and they all return the same faulty information. On my desktop PC, using Chrome returns the same. I switched to Microsoft Edge and Wolfram Cloud returns the same. MacBook with safari returns the same.

If I run it on my desktop Mathematica 12.1 and it returns the correct `GeoPosition[{40.1, -80.64}]`. My account type is "Basic" and I am logged in. I am on my school's private network and my pc is connected via ethernet. The rest are connected through wifi. Any insight would be appreciated.